# Moq Setup Adding With Same "Filter" instead of overwriting

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I am trying to mock a DbSet<> in Moq where I can add to the list of entities in the DbSet<>.  In other words, a mutable DbSet<>.

I have some extension methods written for this, but have distilled the problem down into a single test.

I *thought* in Moq if you Setup the same call with the same parameters (filter), the Setup is replaced?

But, yet, this below unit test shows that it is added?

See 'below throws "Expected collection to contain 1 item(s), but found 2."'

```
        [Fact]
        public void Add2Test()
        {
            var contextMock = new Mock<IDbContext>();
            List<MyEntity> data = new List<MyEntity>(){new MyEntity()};
            var queryable = data.AsQueryable();
            var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>();
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
            contextMock.Setups.Where(s => s.Expression.ReturnType == typeof(DbSet<MyEntity>)).Should().HaveCount(0);
            contextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<MyEntity>()).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
            contextMock.Setups.Where(s => s.Expression.ReturnType == typeof(DbSet<MyEntity>)).Should().HaveCount(1);
            // let's do it again
            data = new List<MyEntity>() { new MyEntity() };
            queryable = data.AsQueryable();
            mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>();
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
            mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<MyEntity>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
            contextMock.Setups.Where(s => s.Expression.ReturnType == typeof(DbSet<MyEntity>)).Should().HaveCount(1);
            contextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<MyEntity>()).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);
            // below throws "Expected collection to contain 1 item(s), but found 2."
            contextMock.Setups.Where(s => s.Expression.ReturnType == typeof(DbSet<MyEntity>)).Should().HaveCount(1);
        }
```

Comment: What if you comment all the lines of `let's do it again` except last line i.e. `contextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<MyEntity>()).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);` then do you get the same error? What if you set using `It.IsAny<MyEntity>` then do you see the same error?

Comment: >>What if you comment all the lines of let's do it again except last line i.e. contextMock.Setup(x => x.Set<MyEntity>()).Returns(mockDbSet.Object);<<

I imagine the error would go away, but that would defeat the purpose of trying to "refresh" the data.

>>What if you set using It.IsAny<MyEntity><<
I am not sure where you mean by that?

Comment: If the intention here to refresh the data then do you need to initialize the object  `mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>();`? I believe if you comment that line and keep the remaining same even then you won't get the behaviour you have mentioned in your question...
Now about your behavior, I believe you are getting that because object reference has changed on line `mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<MyEntity>>();` that's why it is returning 2 count of setups..

Comment: So, your hypothesis is because there is 2nd return object, that's why there is two Setups?

Comment: Yes, that's my hypothesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my observations writing libraries such as [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing), [MemoryCache.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/MemoryCache.Testing) etc, Moq does not replace/override existing setups that are the same.

Though it's a Moq implementation detail, currently if you setup the same expression more than once the last setup added will be used.

```
void Main()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();
    mock.Setup(x => x.Bar()).Returns("A");
    mock.Setup(x => x.Bar()).Returns("B");
    var mocked = mock.Object;
    Console.WriteLine(mocked.Bar());
    Console.WriteLine(mock.Setups.Select(x => x.ToString()));
}

public interface IFoo
{
    public string Bar();
}
```

[image]